# List sorting by related field C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Please, help me to write a correct-working code.
I have tried to search some letters in the Internet, but it didn't help me.

I have a big dictionary with data of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` type (name: "StructureDictionary").

There are different dictionary's keys at the "high-level":

```
[General], [Order], ..., [Group1], [Group5], [Group34], [StaticText3], [Group2], [DynamicPicture2], [StaticText2].
```

I need to make the list of Groups' indexes unsorted `(1, 5, 34, 2...)` and sorted by the Value of `(string)StructureDictionary["[Group*]"]["Group_Name"]` alphabetically.

"Group_Name" is a "low-level" key with string type value and doesn't contains any "high-level" keys.  Besides, some of "Groups" keys don't have the "Group_Name" field or the value of "Group_Name" key is empty or similar with other group. This groups should contains in the end of the final list.

I have made an unsorted indexes list already, but I can't to write correct code for making sorted list. We can sort the existing list or remake new list. The choosing of sorting conditions consists of the CheckBox condition.

```
List<string> Groups = StructureDictionary
      .Where(x => x.Key.Contains("Group"))
      .Select(x => x.Key.Trim(new char[] { '[', ']', ' ' })
      .Remove(0, 5))
      .ToList();

if (SurveySortCheckBox3.Checked == true)
{
    var res =
        from d in Groups
        orderby StructureDictionary[string.Format("[Group{0}]", d)]["Groups_Name"]
        select d;

         Groups = res;
}
```

Please help me to correct (or write new) code in "if-true" branch for making sorted list (for ex: `Groups.Sort()` method), as I described it earlier. For right understanding I've add a picture with example of structure. Thank you for attention.

[image: Example of structure]

Comment: Can you more detailed example? Like initializing the variable StructureDictionary with some values?

Comment: Main problem here is that this seems to be an over-complex and hard to use and maintain data structure. Are you sure you need this? Looked at `dynamic` objects?

Comment: @Handoko.Chen At first, I make an search instruction: var SearchInstr = lines_arr.Where(x => x[0] == '['); Then I add in cycle key-value pairs: var dic = ParamList.Select(x => x.Split('=')).ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]); StructureDictionary.Add(lines_arr[i], dic); Where array contains all lines of file opened.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have no any usable ideas structures, when I've been writing this program. I will look for dynamic objects later when I obtain knowledge needed.

Comment: Check the [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)  class which allows you to add attributes to it at runtime. It's just one implementation of a `dynamic` object but it can replace the inner dictionary quite nicely.